# Display random text based on checkbox selection (javascript)

Tags: javascript, input

I'm getting to grips with Javascript and need to do the following:

Have four checkboxes with the text "Red, Blue, Yellow, Green".  When the user clicks the button, one of the colours will display randomly as text.

Any suggestions how to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Only checked checkboxes count?

Comment: Wait... so you have 4 checkboxes or buttons?

Comment: Wait...so are you saying you have a separate "Go" button, and when that is clicked some text should be displayed in a random colour selected from amongst whichever colours' checkboxes are currently checked? Even if you're confused about the JS you could at least show the html markup that you have so far...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/QgGwS/</kbd>

<sup>*</sup>I am using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) here just for explanatory purposes. Convert it to pure JavaScript if you want to.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $colors = $("input:checked");       //Get all the checkboxes that are checked
    if( $colors.length != 0){           //At least 1 checkbox has to be checked
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*$colors.length); //generate ran. num
        $("span").html($colors[index].value);                 //show the value
    }else{
        alert("Choose a color!");       //Tell the user to check at least 1 box
    }    
});
```

> One of the randomly chosen color from the list of the checked boxes will show up as you click on the button.

Comment: Funnily enough, I slapped together [something rather similar](http://jsfiddle.net/q3jnJ/). Could help OP.

Comment: @Rikonator - Your demo is kind of... overly-complicated.